# get records without records from another table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, orm

I want to get bicycles which are not disliked by user. So if user disliked a bicycle it will never show that bicycle again.

Bicycle has many dislikes and belongs to User.
User has many dislikes and bicycles. 
Dislike belongs to User and Bicycle.

Here is my code in index action of BicyclesController:

```
@bicycles = Bicycle.includes(:dislikes).where.not("dislikes.author_id = #{current_user.id}")
```

So I am getting this error:

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "dislikes"
LINE 1: ...cles" WHERE "bicycles"."published" = $1 AND (NOT (dislikes.a...
                                                             ^
: SELECT  "bicycles".* FROM "bicycles" WHERE "bicycles"."published" = $1 AND (NOT (dislikes.author_id = 1)) LIMIT $2 OFFSET $3
```

**UPDATE**

This query gives me records which are disliked by user:

```
@bicycles = Bicycle.includes(:dislikes).where(dislikes: {author_id: current_user.id})
```

But now I want to exclude these records from all. Is there an efficient way to do this?

Comment: Maybe this codes will work: @bicycles = Bicycle.includes(:dislikes).where("dislikes.author_id != ?",  current_user.id)

Comment: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid - 
`PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "dislikes"
LINE 1: ..."bicycles" WHERE "bicycles"."published" = $1 AND (dislikes.a...
                                                             ^
: SELECT  "bicycles".* FROM "bicycles" WHERE "bicycles"."published" = $1 AND (dislikes.author_id != 1) ORDER BY "bicycles"."published_at" DESC LIMIT $2 OFFSET $3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got needed result by:

```
user_dislikes = current_user.dislikes.map(&:bicycle_id)
@bicycles = Bicycles.where('id NOT in (?)', user_dislikes)
```

Answer (score 0):

PostgresSQL query syntax:

```
 @bicycles = Bicycle.includes(:dislikes).where.not(dislikes: {author_id:  current_user.id})
```

Comment: Your query returns records which are disliked by other users. But I need other. I want `all records -(minus) disliked by user records`

Comment: Try this: @bicycles = Bicycle.includes(:dislikes).where.not(dislikes: {author_id:  nil})

Comment: This one gives all disliked records by any user. Again this is now what I need..:(